# What "<<!" means in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I use this command and get an input prompt. I found it in an auto-ftp script.

```
$ <<!
>
```

I'd like to know its name and, how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<<` followed by any string means *read the input until this string, and output all of this to the standard output*.

So, you will find:

```
<<EOF
Hi,
This is some plain text.
EOF
```

Most of the time, there is a command before `<<`. This means: read the input and send it to the stdin of the command.

So you will find, for instance:

```
cat <<EOF 1>&2
This text is written to the stderr.
EOF
```

But you could write:

```
<<EOF 1>&2
This text is written to the stderr.
EOF
```

The same way, you can sort text:

```
sort <<EOF
A
C
D
B
EOF
```

to get `A B C D` in this order.

Finally, you can use this to pipe to another command:

```
<<EOF | tr a-z A-Z
This is some text. Yes.
EOF
```

to get:

```
THIS IS SOME TEXT. YES.
```

Comment: The `<<EOF |tr a-z A-Z` example is not working in bash 4.4. It has to be `tr a-z A-Z <<EOF`

Comment: Yes, depending on the shell, and on its version, some examples may not be supported. But all are supported with any version of zsh.